# Help Texts in visualforce not working

Tags: apex, visualforce

Created a visualforce page and the fields that have a helptext suddenly don't work. Can't hover over it at all. I have jquery present on the page but other than that it is pretty standard forms. Anyone experience this problem before?

Comment: Showing us a (simplified) example of your Visualforce may help. Else it's stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 5):

Try wrap your outputTex/outputField in pageBlockSectionItem. check this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="/** some helptext - either custom or from field **/">
    <apex:outputLabel value="/** label - either custom or from field **/"/>
    <apex:outputField value="/** some field **/"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Ps. by "from field" I mean this syntax : {!$ObjectType.SobjectAPIName.fields.FieldName.InlineHelpText}

Using the helpText attribute, keep in mind:

> The help text that is displayed next to this field as a hover-based
>   tooltip, similar to the text that is displayed next to standard
>   Salesforce fields if custom help is defined for the field in Setup.
>   Note that help text only displays if the showHeader attribute of the
>   parent page is set to true.

Standard configured help is not always displayed, this behavoir is well documented in the [outputfield documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputField.htm):

> Note that if custom help is defined for the field in Setup, the field
>   must be a child of an `<apex:pageBlock>` or `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`,
>   and the Salesforce page header must be displayed for the custom help
>   to appear on your Visualforce page. To override the display of custom
>   help, use the `<apex:outputField>` in the body of an
>   `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`.

Comment: Hope you don't mind; i added some documentation references.

Comment: Even more - I am happy for it. I am sometimes to lazy for it ;) Thanks! :)

Comment: I think there seems to be a bug for visualforce pages, as i am unable to get helptexts to work for me. Even removing all javascript causes no changes

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned you can include the help text via the helpText attribute of apex:pageBlockSectionItem, but there is another well hidden feature built into the platform that's often easier. [I posted a blog very similar to Birthus' answer in 2011](http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/10/field-level-help-tooltips-in.html), and [another salesforce developer pointed this trick out in a twitter response](https://twitter.com/jeremyross/status/126046284204351488).

If you include an apex:inputField or apex:outputField element as a child of apex:pageBlockSection without including an apex:pageBlockSectionItem tag around it salesforce renders the field's value as expected, but it also renders the field's label and inline help text, if any.

Something like:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Incident__c.FieldSets.PortalNewLower}" var="field">
    <apex:inputField value="{!newIncident[field]}" required="{!field.required || field.DBRequired}" style="width:65%" />
</apex:repeat>
```